# Issue retrieving particular SQL rows

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I'm trying to retrieve particular rows in my database, the setup is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "Rules" ("credit" BOOL NOT NULL , "debit" BOOL NOT NULL , "product_code" INTEGER, "frequency" INTEGER, "percentage" FLOAT, "limit" FLOAT, "below" BOOL, "above" BOOL, "price" FLOAT)
```

My code is:

```
class Process_Rules

    def initialize()
            @rules = Array.new() {Array.new()}
    end

    def process()

        db = SQLite3::Database.open "Checkout.sqlite"
        #############################################

        productRules = db.execute "SELECT product_code FROM Rules WHERE product_code NOT NULL"

        @rules.push([])

        for i in 0..productRules.length

            @rules[0].push(productRules[i])
        end

        #############################################

        limitRules = db.execute "SELECT limit FROM Rules" #ERRORSOME HERE, PREVIOUS SQL STATEMENT EXECUTES FINE

        #############################################

        db.close()
    end
end
```

Error:

```
in 'initialize': near 'limit': syntax error (SQLite3::SQLException)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since LIMIT is a keyword, you'll have to quote it:

```
SELECT "limit" FROM Rules
```

Comment: Thanks, I just figured that out with the limit keyword!

Comment: As the query is already in quotes, I need to use single quotes around limit, not double

Comment: Additionally, it'd probably be a good idea to rename this column.  Best to avoid using keywords in column names.

Comment: `As the query is already in quotes, I need to use single quotes around limit, not double` -- this varies by SQL implementation.  In many SQL implemenations, `SELECT 'limit'` means "select the string literal `limit`" while `SELECT "limit"` means "select the column `limit`".  Pretty sure this holds true in sqllite as well.  You really need double quotes.  http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q24